# How to Automate scripts with options in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, command-line

I'm not a native English speaker as such pardon some discrepancy in my question. I'm looking at a way to Automate option selection in Programs/Scripts running via PowerShell.

For example:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "velociraptor.exe" -ArgumentList "config generate -i"
```

In the above snipper PowerShell will run Velociraptor and initiate the configuration wizard from a Ps1 file. The Wizard has few options. After running it will generate some Yaml files.

[image]

As such what would be the way to have PowerShell Script automate the option selection process? I know what the option should be. I looked around but I don't know proper terms to find what I need. Nor am I sure this can be done with PowerShell.

The end goal is to have the Ps1 download Exe, run the config command and continue with choosing the selection based on predefined choices. So far I gotten download and lunching of the velociraptor.exe working. But not sure how to skip the window in screenshot and have PowerShell script do it instead.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a CLI reference for `velociraptor` at https://www.velocidex.com/, but, **generally speaking, your best bet is to find a *non-interactive* way to provide the information of interest, via dedicated _parameters**_ (possibly pointing to an input file).

Absent that, you can **use the following technique to provide successive responses to an external program's *interactive prompts*, assuming that the program reads the responses from *stdin*** (the standard input stream):

```sh
$responses = 'windows', 'foo', 'bar' # List all responses here
$responses | velociraptor.exe config generate -i
```